# mostrar información almacenada en checkbox con javascript, php y html

Tags: javascript, php, html5, javascript-objeto

Comunidada,

Necesito pasar una cadena de texto almacenada en base de datos sql server como la siguiente "1,2,3" a campos de checkbox que representan los dias de la semana como se muestra a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me tiene que hacer es si tengo el 1,2,3 me marque el domingo que es = 1, el 2 que es igual a lunes y el 3 que es igual a martes, haciendo una simulación de como deberia quedar seria lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pase la cadena a un arreglo de la siguiente manera:

```
var arr = JSON.parse("[" + listas['spot'][0].checkDias + "]");
        console.log( arr)
        console.log(typeof arr[0])
```

esto me genera el siguiente arreglo de manera correcta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora no se como debo pasar esto a la parte grafica en la vista tengo lo siguiente:

```
$('#checkDias').val(listas['spot'][0].checkDias);
$('#checkDias').prop('title', listas['spot'][0].checkDias);
```

y la parte de los check la siguiente:

```
<div class="form-row" style="display: flex; padding-bottom:1.5rem;">
    <div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="lunes">
            <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="lunes"> Lunes </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="3" id="martes">
            <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="martes"> Martes </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="4" id="miercoles">
        <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="miercoles"> Miercoles </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="5" id="jueves">
            <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="jueves"> Jueves </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" style="display: flex; padding-bottom:1.5rem;">
    <div class="form-row" style="display: flex;">
        <div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
            <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="6" id="viernes">
            <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="viernes"> Viernes </label>
        </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="7" id="sabado">
            <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="sabado"> Sabado </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="domingo">
            <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="domingo"> Domingo </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Espero me puedan orientar en como poder marcar como seleccionadas esos datos que son dias en la vista.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que cambies el orden de los dias y empieces por domingo.  Si haces eso puedes resolver tu problema iterando por el array y chequeando las checkboxes correspondientes asi:

```js
var arr = [ 1,2,3 ];

var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  $('input[name=semanaDia\\[\\]]')[arr[i]-1].checked = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row" style="display: flex; padding-bottom:1.5rem;">
<div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="domingo">
            <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="domingo"> Domingo </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="2" id="lunes">
            <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="lunes"> Lunes </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="3" id="martes">
            <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="martes"> Martes </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="4" id="miercoles">
        <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="miercoles"> Miercoles </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="5" id="jueves">
            <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="jueves"> Jueves </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row" style="display: flex; padding-bottom:1.5rem;">
    <div class="form-row" style="display: flex;">
        <div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
            <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="6" id="viernes">
            <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="viernes"> Viernes </label>
        </div>
    <div class="form-check-inline" style="margin-right: 4px;">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="semanaDia[]" type="checkbox" value="7" id="sabado">
            <label class="form-check-label" style="font-weight: 100;" for="sabado"> Sabado </label>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, al realizar el for me dice que no se ha definido la propiedad checked.